# Help with Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to show that the Fourier transform of
$$
{\rm g}\left(t\right)
=
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{1 \over 1 - {\rm i}t}\quad \mbox{is}\quad
{\rm G}\left(w\right) = {\rm e}^{-\omega}\quad \mbox{for}\quad \omega > 0\ \mbox{and}\ 0\ \mbox{otherwise.}
$$
Any ideas?

Comment: Compute the inverse Fourier transform of $G$?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, $g$ is not an $L^1$ function, and thus Fourier Transform of $g$ can not be calculated in the traditional way.

Fortunately, $G$ is an $L^1$ function, and this allows us to calculate its inverse Fourier Transform as
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} wt}G(w)\, dw=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} wt}\mathrm{e}^{-w} dw.
$$